# How can I change the django-leaflet openlayers canvas?

Tags: django, leaflet, openlayers, django-leaflet

I have a django-leaflet widget, but the widget shows some imagery instead of openlayers map, how can i change this on modelform?

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.gis.forms import OSMWidget, PointField, ModelForm
from leaflet.forms.widgets import LeafletWidget


    class YourMapWidget(LeafletWidget):
    geometry_field_class = 'geom'

class ApartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Apartment
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'geom': YourMapWidget()}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change it globally using the settings. If you want to use OSM, just add something like this to your settings,

```
LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
    'DEFAULT_CENTER': (6.0, 45.0),
    'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 16,
    'TILES': 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
}
```

BTW, it's actually weird, the default settings should be OSM map.

[django-leaflet docs](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html)

Comment: The one I see is NASA worldview, and it is hardly visible. I already set `LEAFLET_CONFIG` in settings.py.

Comment: Apparently, It isn't OSM tile, instead, it is a blurred NASA Worldview tile, @cabesuon.

Comment: Can you add a screen capture, where it shows map and attribution

Comment: Added screen print.

Comment: As I thought, you have a mix of widgets. Now, by the picture, you are using the GeoDjango widget that uses OpenLayers and that by default has a NASA map (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/#). Which one do you want to use?

Comment: The NASA Worldview is not visible so I prefer OpenLayers.

Comment: Excuse me, I see that on admin page, the leaflet openstreet map is fine, it is in the form template that renders incorrectly as imagery.